# How to store uploaded images inside Draft js to Firestore (Reactjs)?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, draftjs

To all Reactjs programmer experts, I am currently facing an issue on storing the uploaded images inside the Draftjs Rich Text Editor to Firestore database.

What I am doing right now is directly storing the whole EditorState content to Firestore documents. But because of the Firestore per document storage has a maximum limit of 1mb, so when I am trying to upload multiple images, when the files size exceed 1mb, Firestore returns me an error.

Please advise me on the proper way to store and retrieve the images to Draftjs Rich Text Editor.

Thanks in advance!

This is my code on storing Draftjs content to Firestore.

```
  db.collection('post')
    .add({
        content: {
          state_content: JSON.stringify(
                  convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()),
                  null
                ),
                html_content: stateToHTML(editorState.getCurrentContent()),
              },
   
    })
```

Note: This is what I stored inside state_content.

```
{"blocks":[{"key":"4qeoj","text":"","type":"unstyled","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}},{"key":"198jv","text":" ","type":"atomic","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[],"entityRanges":[{"offset":0,"length":1,"key":0}],"data":{}},{"key":"3qcg1","text":"","type":"unstyled","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}}],"entityMap":{"0":{"type":"IMAGE","mutability":"IMMUTABLE","data":{"src":"data:image/png;base64,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......."}}}}
```

Comment: Why don't you store images somewhere in cloud servers and store just their paths in DraftJS content?